# knn search using HDF5

Tags: python, bigdata, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor, pytables

I'm trying to do knn search on big data with limited memory.

I'm using HDF5 and python.

I tried bruteforce linear search(using pytables) and kd-tree search (using sklearn)

It's suprising but kd-tree method takes more time(maybe kd-tree will work better if we increase batch size? but I don't know optimal size also it limited by memory)

Now I'm looking for how to speed up calculations, I think HDF5 file can be tuned for individual PC, also norm calculation can be speeded maybe using nymexpr or some python tricks.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import tables
import cProfile

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

rows = 10000
cols = 1000
batches = 100
k= 10

#USING HDF5
vec= np.random.rand(1,cols)
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols)
fileName = 'C:\carray1.h5'
shape = (rows*batches, cols)  # predefined size
atom = tables.UInt8Atom()  #?
filters = tables.Filters(complevel=5, complib='zlib') #?

#create
# h5f = tables.open_file(fileName, 'w')
# ca = h5f.create_carray(h5f.root, 'carray', atom, shape, filters=filters)

# for i in range(batches):
    # ca[i*rows:(i+1)*rows]= data[:]+i  # +i to modify data

# h5f.close()

#can be parallel?
def test_bruteforce_knn():
    h5f = tables.open_file(fileName)

    t0= time.time()
    d = np.empty((rows*batches,))
    for i in range(batches):
        d[i*rows:(i+1)*rows] = ((h5f.root.carray[i*rows:(i+1)*rows]-vec)**2).sum(axis=1)
    print (time.time()-t0)
    ndx = d.argsort()
    print ndx[:k]

    h5f.close()

def test_tree_knn():
    h5f = tables.open_file(fileName)

        # it will not work
    # t0= time.time()
    # nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=k, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(h5f.root.carray)
    # distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(vec)
    # print (time.time()-t0)

        #need to concatenate distances, indices somehow 
    t0= time.time()
    d = np.empty((rows*batches,))
    for i in range(batches):
        nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=k, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(h5f.root.carray[i*rows:(i+1)*rows])
        distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(vec)  # put in dict? 
        #d[i*rows:(i+1)*rows] = 
    print (time.time()-t0)
    #ndx = d.argsort()
    #print ndx[:k]

    h5f.close()

cProfile.run('test_bruteforce_knn()')
cProfile.run('test_tree_knn()')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your data has 1000 dimensions? If this is the case then it's expected that kd-tree won't fare well as it suffers from the curse of dimensionality.

You might want to have a look at Approximate Nearest Neighbors search methods instead. For instance have a look at [flann](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/).

Comment: Yes 1k, maybe I mistaken but by kd-tree I mean NearestNeighbors in sklearn.neighbors.Yes I know about flann(it seems it have native sapport of hdf5), but it need to be compiled.

Comment: Well the scikit-learn implementation of kd-tree and ball-tree also need to be compiled. NearestNeighbors is a wrapper class that delegates the NN query to individual algorithms (kd-tree, ball-tree or bruteforce) depending on its constructor parameters.

Comment: I mean that scikit-learn is simple to install(without compiling), my tests show that using bruteforce with hdf5 with max compression level is faster than kd-tree, ball-tree or bruteforce in scikit-learn.I don't understand why *-tree methods are slower.

Comment: Because for high-dim data, the overhead of building a tree kills the performance. Also, a brute force approach will use vectorized CPU instructions (e.g. using fast linear algebra routine from BLAS) that is not possible to leverage as efficiently in a tree datastructure.

Comment: kd-tree and ball-tree typically work faster than bruteforce with `n_dimensions` in the `[1, 100]` range.

Comment: I found this for large dimensions http://www.slaney.org/malcolm/yahoo/Slaney2008-LSHTutorial.pdf "locality-sensitive hashing for finding nearest neighbors" .It seems it's not implemented in scikit-learn yet.

Comment: As I said flann already has state of the art methods implemented. Have a look at the papers in the publications of their website. They compare various methods that perform better than a naive data independent LSH.